# Leaflet remove GeoJSON object from the layer

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I've this:

```
var AllProjectArray = L.geoJSON();
```

The using addData()

```
AllProjectArray.addData(somefeatures)
```

Now I've my AllProjectArray filled and working

Now I want to remove from AllProjectArray one specific feature, something like AllProjectArray.removeData(thisfeatures).

I've tried with

```
AllProjectArray.removeLayer(..);
```

whit no luck. Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GeoJSON layer is in Leaflet a group layer where each feature is member layer of this group. You can iterate through all members by `eachLayer` group layer method.

If you want to remove particular feature/member from GeoJSON layer, you have to somehov identify it, by id or some property. Let's say we want to remove feature with particular feature id.

One possibilty is that each time we want to remove feature, we loop through all members od GeoJSON layer and remove the one with desired id. Function for removing feature could look something like this:

```
function removeFeature(layerGroup, featureId) {
  layerGroup.eachLayer(function(layer){
    if (layer.feature.id == featureId) {
      layerGroup.removeLayer(layer);
    }
  });
}
```

We would then remove feature with desired id by call

```
removeFeature(AllProjectArray, id);
```

To avoid looping through all features at each remove, we can create object which connects feature id with internal Leaflet layer id:

```
var AllProjectArray = L.geoJSON();
AllProjectArray.addData(somefeatures);

var layerID = {};
AllProjectArray.eachLayer(function(layer) {
  layerID[layer.feature.id] = AllProjectArray.getLayerId(layer);
});
```

Removing feature with desired id is then done without any iteration with simple call:

```
AllProjectArray.removeLayer(layerID[id]);
```

Comment: Thanks for elucidation

Comment: Thanks, I managed to solve my problem with your suggestion!